# How to have a IE.css that overrides part of standard.css?

Tags: css, deprecated

I'm trying to apply *some* CSS that's only for older IE browser.

The way to do that seems to be with an IF IE tag in the .html
So I'm thinking the most elegant way to do that is to have:

*Standard.css*
and then put the .css that is different, only for IE, in
*IE.css*

And then  reference the IE.css but only if it's an IE browser.
So IE browsers get *both* CSSs.

And there's the issue:

I want to make sure that the IE.css overrules the same named elements in *Standard.css*.

IE.css will have the same styles, just different values.

**UPDATE:**

I am trying to avoid having two alternative .css files. I want to have a *standard.css* and then a small IE.css that has only css rules that I want to override for IE>

So IE would render *standard.css* + have some rules in it overriden by *IE.css*

Example:

If Standard.css has 10 rules and only 2 of them needed to be different for IE then I'd like to have:
Standard.css with 10 rules.
IE.css with *just 2 rules* that override 2 rules in Standard.css

That way, when I make changes to Standard.css that don't involve IE (which is 99% of those rules) I don't have to make changes to IE.css as well.

Comment: Sure, just make sure the <link> to IE.css is after the link for Standard.css

Comment: I'm not sure I see a question here. You have outlined a way of realizing styles which apply to IE only (generally termed conditional comments). So, go for it.

Comment: Just keep in mind that conditional comments are no longer supported in IE 10 and up. See https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms537512(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: @TheOneandOnlyChemistryBlob that's not a good way to go. If a rule in standard shouldn't be applied in IE and it isn't overridden, it will still appear.

Comment: @zero298, can you clarify that point?  As long as every rule that should NOT be applied to IE9 and below is listed in IE.css and IE.css link comes AFTER Standard.css, then it would work?

Answer (score 2):

If your target old IE versions you could think of conditional style sheets:
https://css-tricks.com/how-to-create-an-ie-only-stylesheet/

```
<!--[if IE]>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="all-ie-only.css" />
<![endif]-->
```

For newer IE's you could consider adding a special attribute to your HTML-tag and apply all styles to this attribute as suggested here: https://css-tricks.com/ie-10-specific-styles/

```
html[data-useragent*='MSIE 10.0'] h1 {
  color: blue;
}
```

combined with a script

```
var doc = document.documentElement;
doc.setAttribute('data-useragent', navigator.userAgent);
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to target all version of IE put your styles here:

```
<!--[if IE]>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="all-ie-only.css" />
<![endif]-->
```

If you want to choose exact IE version use this code:

```
<!--[if IE [ie_number]>     
   <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="ie[ie_number].css">
<![endif]-->
```

This code also should be behind links to normal CSS (then it will override your default styles).

Comment: Conditional comments are  no longer supported in IE 10 and up.